# .on("pagecreate") not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy this code: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5qe6g/1/

I'm using goolge blogger

I've got my imports in the template html

```
<head>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/scripts/app.ui-1.0.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

problem is that "onpagecreate" is not being called. If I get rid of it like this:

```
function createList(menudata){
    var html = '';
    $.each(menudata,function(i,val){
        html += '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true" data-id='+val.productId+'><h3>'+val.name+'</h3><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
        $.each(val.productoption,function(i,val){
            html += '<li class="row">'+val.topping+'</li>';
        });
        html += '</ul></div>';
    });
    return html;
}

    var menulistitem = createList(data);
    $('#menu-content').empty().append(menulistitem);
    $('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
    $('div ul').listview();
```

It draws the menu, but its not collapsible. I'm assuming that the reason its not collapsible is that the timing is off

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're loading multiple versions of jquery and jquery.mobile. Don't do that.

Comment: You're also missing some of the `</script>` tags. You can't combine it with `<script>` by making it `<script .../>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `head` tag of your `html` file. First of all you don't need multiple load of same files. Problem is that you put `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css` CSS file in script tag. CSS file need to come in link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```

After clearing some unnecessary loading of jquery your head tag from external resources only need this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Check out working code : [codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbxgyW)